# How to pass flatten dim tensor to Conv2D in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensor

I am curious how I can pass flatten dim input to `Conv2D` where I started with RGB image input but I did some transformation and got 1 dim tensor which I want to pass convolutional filter for feature extraction. When I passed flatten tensor to `Conv2D`, I got the following value error:

```
> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_12 is incompatible with the layer:
> expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 784]
```

**my attempt**:

> ```
> x.get_shape()
> TensorShape([None, 784, 3, 1])
> x_new = Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_sum(tf.squeeze(x, axis=-1), axis=-1))(x)
> h = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x_new)
> h = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(h)
> h = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(h)
> ```

I am wondering is it possible to pass flatten dim tensor `x_new` to `Conv2D`. Any way to do this in tensorflow? any idea to make this happen? thanks

Comment: Try to change the `TensorShape` to `TensorShape([None, 784])`

Comment: @MostafaLabib I don't get it. above I printed out shape of input tensor `x` : TensorShape([None, 784, 3, 1]). I used `x` and got `x_new` for some purpose then pass it to `Conv2D`. any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` has the shape `TensorShape([None, 784, 3, 1])`. But afterwards in your Lambda-Layer your use `squeeze` to reduce the dimension to `TensorShape([None, 784, 3])`, thats fine. Afterwards you sum up over the last channel and change the dimension to `TensorShape([None, 3])`.The problem is that keras and tensorflow always works with the shape `[batch_number,heigth, width, channels]` but now you just sepcified `[batch,channels]`. You now can use `tf.expand_dims(x_new,axis=-1)` twice to extend the shape to `TensorShape([None, 3,1,1])` to build up a 3-row-1-column vector. I think if `Zero-Padding` is activated so it shouldnt be a problem to use a `3x3 Kernel` :). So in short thats the code you propably need:

```
x_new = Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=2),axis=-1))(x)
```

***EDIT:***

After chatting in private Chat, this Code solved the problem:

```
def test(image_shape):

  in_image = Input(shape=image_shape)

  x_new = Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=2),axis=-1))(in_image) # Sum up over the third dimension and afterwards expand the dims

  b = tf.shape(x_new) # get the shape of the Lambda layer

  x_new = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([28,28,1], input_shape=b) (x_new) # reshape to [None 28 28 1] Image
  h = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x_new) # Conv
  h = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(h)# Conv

model = Model(in_image, h)
return model

mod=test([None,784, 3, 1]) # Declare image-shape for the model input

aa = tf.constant(1,shape=[1,784, 3, 1]) # input a test image with only ones in it

bb = tf.constant(1,shape=[3,784, 3, 1]) # Changing batch sizes work aswell

aa_result = mod.predict(aa)

bb_result = mod.predict(bb)
```

Comment: how do I understand from `TensorShape([None, 784, 3, 1])` to `TensorShape([None, 784, 1, 1])`? trace back to origin, I used `taylor series` to expand gray-scale images, and `x_new` is output of taylor series. I want to know your output is correct. Thanks

Comment: I dont understand your question sorry ^^ you need the shape ´[batch_number, width, heigth, channels]´ if your want to pass the tensor into a keras / tensorflow element. But after using your lambda layer your Tensor is in the shape of [None,3], to use it in the Convoluition, which is a keras / tf Operation you need another shape. So extending the shape, leads to a usable one. Which you can process with your Convolution. What is the Shape that you want out of your Lambda layer ? Hope i could help :)

Comment: make sense. so what would be input_shape for Conv2D? like (784,1,1)? it means that passing width=784, height=1, num_channel=1? to me, it might do (28,28,3), but now I got `TensorShape([784, 1, 1])`. any thought? thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly. But after your Lambda layer you get the shape [None,3], because you squeeze and tf_reduce_sum. None is for the Batch_number and 3 is either weidth, heigth or channel_number, however you want to interpret the sum of the 784 values.

Comment: so what would be correct input_shape for `Conv2D` after we tried the above solution and got `TensorShape([None, 784, 1, 1])` ? means of [784,1,1] is 784 pixels in 3-dim arrays? am I right? can you clarify which input_shape I should pass after I tried your solution above? thanks

Comment: You can use ´TensorShape([None, 784, 1, 1]´ or reshape it into ´[None,28,28,3]´. Both is possible, but the Conv2D is performing the Convolution in two different ways. if your use the first shape, you neglect spatial information, because you rearranged the image into a one-column vector. If your image was before a RGB image for example, you propably should reshape to [None,28,28,3] to get those spatial information back into the correct order. But only if you want that, that depends on your objective. But thats another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217176/discussion-between-kim-and-paul-higazi).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reshape?

```
tf.reshape(tf.shape(x), shape=(28, 28, 1))
```

Comment: I got this error after I tried above:  `ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 2 elements to shape [28,28,1] (784 elements) for '{{node Reshape_1}} = Reshape[T=DT_INT32, Tshape=DT_INT32](Shape, Reshape_1/shape)' with input shapes: [2], [3] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [28,28,1].`. any idea why?

Comment: Are you getting your shape? x.get_shape()? Try tf.shape(x) instead.

Comment: yeah,` x.get_shape()`: TensorShape([None, 784, 3, 1]). how to make this work? thanks

Comment: How are you using the reshape code. Could you show the code.

Comment: I just tried above attempt you gave and it is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217171/discussion-between-kim-and-isaac-ng).